# Interface parameters

Tags: c#, interface

I am a bit confused on how to implement this.

I have defined an interface called IActivity with a few properties in int.

I have then created two classes that implement this interface and add a few extra properties

EngagementActivity and MPEngagementActivity. To be clear these two classes implement IActivity and declare a few extra properties

I then have a base class called ActivitySvc which will implement virtual methods for all the functionality that is common to both type of activities.

I then implement two classes that  derive from the base class and have to provide their own implementation of the SaveActivity method declared in the base class:

```
public abstract void SaveActivity(IActivity activity);
```

My problem is that I am getting errors when implementing the SaveActivity method because my activity object is of type IActivity and therefore it doesn't have the members specific to the EngagementActivity and MPEngagementActivity classes.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using an interface, you generally *don't* care what is the underlying data, just that it implements the interface. Sounds like you are trying to violate that.

Comment: What do these different members from the IActivity concrete classes represent? Instead of trying to access them directly from the SaveActivity method, can you hide that away inside of the EngagementActivity and MPEngagementActivity classes and wrap the logic into a common method exposed via IActivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it may not necessarily be the best/most correct approach, the quickest approach would be to try and safely cast your activity object to the correct type in the relevant methods.

For example, in the class that uses EngagementActivity, you could do something like so:

```
public override void SaveActivity(IActivity activity)
{
    var engagementActivity = activity as EngagementActivity;
    if (engagementActivity != null) // it's the correct type
    {
        // Do whatever's needed here
    }
}
```

If the `engagementActivity` variable is null, it's not the type you're trying to cast it as. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) for more info on 'as'.

Answer (score 1):

Get the underlying type of IActivity in SaveActivity and get your properties.
You can define virtual method in abstract class which you can do not override

```
public virtual void SaveActivity(IActivity activity)
{
    ...
    // some common code for all types
    if(activity is EngagementActivity)
    {
       // use explicit type casting '(EngagementActivity)activity' and get your properties
       // save your data
       return;
    }
    if(activity is MPEngagementActivity)
    {
       // use explicit type casting '(MPEngagementActivity)activity' and get your properties
       // save your data
       return;
    }
    // other activity types
    ...
    // if no case fired save data for common activity or throw exception for unknown type
}
```

Comment: I declared the SaveActivity method as abstract as the implementation is quite different depending on the Activity, but I did implement your suggestion of casting the object to the right type.